# How to merge or copy photos and albums from multiple Google Photos accounts?

Tags: google-photos

I want to consolidate a number of free (under 15GB) Google Photos accounts into a single paid account (2 terabytes).  I've seen posts that explain how to share the entire library with a "partner" account and that allows copying photos.  However, none of these methods copy over the albums into the new account.  The albums are the most important part since they have been manually curated.  And I have lots of them.

Is there a way to bring over photos and albums into a new account?  I don't mind paying for a commercial solution.

Comment: Sounds like you've already invested a fair bit into Google album. I'm not sure I would myself.  Having said that maybe using a script to retrieve the album info from one account and then create it in another saw this that might help [GPhotoApp uses 
GAS for retrieving & creating albums & media items using Google Photo API](https://github.com/tanaikech/GPhotoApp).  I know nothing about this project but it seems like a possibility. If you are looking at commercial pay someone to write some script for you.

Comment: Why were there multiple accounts in the first place?